# array de expedientes en json

Tags: json, php5

sigo con la dichosa api y la tarea es que me muestre los expedientes presentados por un determinado profesional.
Esta parte logro hacerla, pero cuando quiero mostrar los resultados, me salen unos array vacíos que no se como limpiarlos.

Adjuto una parte de la respuesta de la api

{ "meta": { "total-records": 9, "total-pages": 1, "records-on-this-page": 9 }, "data": [ { "type": "KNN_TareasExpediente", "id": "2d59b439-5dcb-e5f5-fe29-5d4c8223df6f", "attributes": { "name": "PROYECTO/DT/RT - ARCOR SA.", "date_entered": "2019-08-08T20:15:00+00:00", "date_modified": "2019-08-08T20:15:00+00:00", "modified_user_id": "f01d0b79-ecf0-073f-de47-5b5f4c9970b7", "modified_by_name": "Martin Diaz", "created_by": "f01d0b79-ecf0-073f-de47-5b5f4c9970b7", "created_by_name": "Martin Diaz", "description": "", "deleted": "0", "created_by_link": "", "modified_user_link": "", "assigned_user_id": "f01d0b79-ecf0-073f-de47-5b5f4c9970b7", "assigned_user_name": "Martin Diaz", "assigned_user_link": "", "SecurityGroups": "", "numero": "", "matriculado_dni": "", "comitente_nombre": "", "comitente_dni": "", "certificado": "", "fecha_baja": "", "observacion": "", "tarea": "25115", "fecha_alta": "2019-08-08", "recibido_por": "", "aviso": "", "fecha_aviso": "", "regional": "", "porcentaje": "100.00", "monto_honorario": "0.00", "monto_obra": "0.00000000", "carpetas": "3", "obra_direccion": "Jujuy 441", "obra_cp": "5000", "obra_localidad": "cordoba", "rcontratoascensores_c": false, "expediente_fisico_c": false, "estado_de_caja_c": "", "knn_tareasexpediente_documents_1": "", "fecha_salida_c": "2019-08-08", "retirado_por_c": "", "distribuidor_c": "", "obra_c": "AUTOTRANPORTADORA NO MOTORA ", "visador_c": "", "opportunities_knn_tareasexpediente_1": "", "opportunities_knn_tareasexpediente_1_name": "50144 - RODRIGUEZ CARMEN E. - ARCOR SA. - Instalaciones Eléctricas", "opportunities_knn_tareasexpediente_1opportunities_ida": "4fd105ac-1375-9106-346f-5d4c82f9cc4f", "tipo_tarea_c": "PROYECTO/DT/RT", "lbl_regional_ingreso_c": "CBA.", "knn_tareasexpediente_knn_pedido_de_facturacion_1": "", "accounts_knn_tareasexpediente_1": "", "accounts_knn_tareasexpediente_1_name": "RODRIGUEZ CARMEN E.", "accounts_knn_tareasexpediente_1accounts_ida": 557, "nombreretira_c": "Martin Diaz", "ascensores_c": "0", "knn_tareasexpediente_activities_1_emails": "", "fechainicioobra_c": "", "es_epec_c": "0", "knn_tareasexpediente_activities_1_tasks": "", "user_id_c": "", "ersep_c": "", "observacion_tarea_c": "", "knn_tareasexpediente_knn_aportes_terceros_1": "", "knn_tareasexpediente_activities_1_notes": "", "knn_comitente_knn_tareasexpediente_1": "", "knn_comitente_knn_tareasexpediente_1_name": "ARCOR SA.", "knn_comitente_knn_tareasexpediente_1knn_comitente_ida": "e70611883d2760c8bbafb4acb29e3446", "documentacionit_c": "", "es_ersep_c": "0", "knn_tareasexpediente_aos_pdf_templates_1": "", "epec_c": "", "es_particular_c": "0", "migrada_c": "1", "esta_en_sector_c": "", "knn_tareasexpediente_activities_1_meetings": "", "knn_tareasexpediente_activities_1_calls": "", "estado_tarea_c": "Pendiente", "nro_caja_c": "", "fechadeingresoersep_c": "", "registro_digital_c": "" }, "links": { "self": "V8/module/KNN_TareasExpediente/2d59b439-5dcb-e5f5-fe29-5d4c8223df6f" } }, { "type": "KNN_TareasExpediente", "id": "3edc1fd9-05a4-de93-1bbe-627c1f2b2d58", "attributes": { "name": " - ", "date_entered": "2022-05-11T20:42:00+00:00", "date_modified": "2022-05-11T20:42:00+00:00", "modified_user_id": "62365376-2acd-faea-1a26-6272c2cd9f18", "modified_by_name": "Alejandro Arla WEB", "created_by": "62365376-2acd-faea-1a26-6272c2cd9f18", "created_by_name": "Alejandro Arla WEB", "description": "", "deleted": "0", "created_by_link": "", "modified_user_link": "", "assigned_user_id": "", "assigned_user_name": "", "assigned_user_link": "", "SecurityGroups": "", "numero": "", "matriculado_dni": "", "comitente_nombre": "", "comitente_dni": "", "certificado": "", "fecha_baja": "", "observacion": "", "tarea": "55588", "fecha_alta": "2022-05-11", "recibido_por": "", "aviso": "", "fecha_aviso": "", "regional": "", "porcentaje": "0.00", "monto_honorario": "0.00", "monto_obra": "0.00000000", "carpetas": "3", "obra_direccion": "Laprida 105 7a", "obra_cp": "", "obra_localidad": "", "rcontratoascensores_c": "0", "expediente_fisico_c": "0", "estado_de_caja_c": "", "knn_tareasexpediente_documents_1": "", "fecha_salida_c": "", "retirado_por_c": "", "distribuidor_c": "", "obra_c": "", "visador_c": "", "opportunities_knn_tareasexpediente_1": "", "opportunities_knn_tareasexpediente_1_name": "50163 - RODRIGUEZ CARMEN E. - ARLA ALEJANDRO - Ambiente", "opportunities_knn_tareasexpediente_1opportunities_ida": "a3dea485-bdf1-0cfc-cba9-627c1fbabff5", "tipo_tarea_c": "", "lbl_regional_ingreso_c": "", "knn_tareasexpediente_knn_pedido_de_facturacion_1": "", "accounts_knn_tareasexpediente_1": "", "accounts_knn_tareasexpediente_1_name": "RODRIGUEZ CARMEN E.", "accounts_knn_tareasexpediente_1accounts_ida": 557, "nombreretira_c": "", "ascensores_c": "0", "knn_tareasexpediente_activities_1_emails": "", "fechainicioobra_c": "", "es_epec_c": "0", "knn_tareasexpediente_activities_1_tasks": "", "user_id_c": "", "ersep_c": "", "observacion_tarea_c": "", "knn_tareasexpediente_knn_aportes_terceros_1": "", "knn_tareasexpediente_activities_1_notes": "", "knn_comitente_knn_tareasexpediente_1": "", "knn_comitente_knn_tareasexpediente_1_name": "", "knn_comitente_knn_tareasexpediente_1knn_comitente_ida": "", "documentacionit_c": "", "es_ersep_c": "0", "knn_tareasexpediente_aos_pdf_templates_1": "", "epec_c": "", "es_particular_c": "0", "migrada_c": "0", "esta_en_sector_c": "", "knn_tareasexpediente_activities_1_meetings": "", "knn_tareasexpediente_activities_1_calls": "", "estado_tarea_c": "Pendiente", "nro_caja_c": "", "fechadeingresoersep_c": "", "registro_digital_c": "" }, "links": { "self": "V8/module/KNN_TareasExpediente/3edc1fd9-05a4-de93-1bbe-627c1f2b2d58" } },

Estimo que los array vacíos corresponden a lo que me muestra en meta: y yo lo que quiero que recorra el array a partir de data.
El código es este:

```
<?php
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
CURLOPT_URL =>  
'https://devphp7.democrm.com.ar/crmciec712/Api/V8/module/Accounts/'.$id.'/...,
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
'Authorization: Bearer '.$permiso,
),
));
$response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
$datos1 = json_decode($response, true);
foreach ($datos1 as $valor) {
for ($i = 0; $i < count($valor); $i++) {
$name = $valor[$i]['id'];
$expe = $valor[$i]['attributes']['name'];
$tarea = $valor[$i]['attributes']['tipo_tarea_c'];
$estado = $valor[$i]['attributes']['estado_tarea_c']; 
echo "
id expediente: $name<br>
Expediente: $expe<br>
Tarea: $tarea<br>
Estado: $estado <br><br>";
 }
}
```

el resultado es este:

id expediente:
Expediente:
Tarea:
Estado:

id expediente:
Expediente:
Tarea:
Estado:

id expediente:
Expediente:
Tarea:
Estado:

id expediente: 2d59b439-5dcb-e5f5-fe29-5d4c8223df6f
Expediente: PROYECTO/DT/RT - ARCOR SA.
Tarea: PROYECTO/DT/RT
Estado: Pendiente

Gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hazlo de este modo y será más practico:

```
foreach ($datos1['data'] as $valor) {
    $name = $valor['id'];
    $expe = $valor['attributes']['name'];
    $tarea = $valor['attributes']['tipo_tarea_c'];
    $estado = $valor['attributes']['estado_tarea_c']; 
    echo "
    id expediente: $name<br>
    Expediente: $expe<br>
    Tarea: $tarea<br>
    Estado: $estado <br><br>";
}
```

### Explicación:

- En el **foreach** he sustituido el **$datos1** por **$datos1['data']** pues has indicado que solo quieres leer ese array de objetos.
- He quitado el **for** porque no funcionaba como esperabas, y en esta solución no hace falta, pues ya recorremos los objetos de `data` (convertidos a array) en el propio *foreach*.
- Al quitar el **for** tambien he quitado los índices **[$i]** de cada **$valor** por lo mismo, ya no hacen falta.

El principal problema lo tenias en el **for**, el cual al pasar por el contenido de **['meta']** como *$valor* intentaba sacarle un número de índice que no tenia **[$i]**, pues tan solo tenia 3 claves con sus respectivos valores, no arrays, e imprimia resultados vacios por eso en cada ciclo del *for*.

Si hubieras mirado el registro de errores de tu web hubieras visto todos los errores **PHP Warning** relacionados con el problema. Cuando tengas dudas acude al log de tu web para más información.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias